# How can I show small values in the react chart 2 donut chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I am using donut chart. Since there is a lot of difference between the values, I cannot see some values in color on the chart. How can I do that. I will show the values ​​as the text below. It also changes when I click on the color boxes above. But it should look 5 colors I want in the cake

```
const newData = [11973.57,253.83,17280, 4451.81,154.16]
const options = {
legend: {
display: true
},
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
animation: false,
cutoutPercentage: 80,
layout: { padding: 0 },
tooltips: {
enabled: true,
mode: 'index',
intersect: false,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: theme.palette.divider,
backgroundColor: theme.palette.white,
titleFontColor: theme.palette.text.primary,
bodyFontColor: theme.palette.text.secondary,
footerFontColor: theme.palette.text.secondary
},
offset:true
};
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD3Kz.png